# Is __attribute__((packed)) GCC only, or cross platform?

Tags: c, gcc

Is `__attribute__((packed))` GCC only, or cross platform?

If it's GCC only, how can I check if I am compiling on GCC?

So I can do this for a cross-platform packed structure:

```c
#if /*COMPILING_ON_GCC*/
#   define Packed __attribute__((packed))
#else
#   define Packed
#endif

struct MyStruct {
    char A;
    int B;
    long C;
    //...
} Packed;
```

If it's GCC, `Packed` will be replaced with `__attribute__((packed))`, and if it's not, it will be replaced with nothing, and not cause any problems.

BTW I LOVE POUND DEFINE MACROS!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's supported by gcc and clang, but it's not part of the C standard and other compilers will not necessarily support it.  For instance, MSVC does not.

Other compilers may provide similar functionality using different syntax, e.g. `#pragma pack`.  But there is no one way to do it that will work everywhere.

You can try some examples on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/tFEqD-).

You can determine whether you're compiling with gcc by testing if the `__GNUC__` macro is defined.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define Packed __attribute__((packed));
#else
#define Packed /* nothing */
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

No attributes or pragmas are cross platform. They are a compiler extension and have to be avoided in the portable code.

> So I can do this for a cross-platform packed structure:

If you do not care about the packing, so why are you going to use it. Remember that packing comes with serious performance penalty on many platforms.

Comment: I think that this is wrong. There are standard attributes such as [[noreturn]], which are defined in standard https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes On the other hand there also exist attributes that are platform-dependent [[gnu::may_alias]]

Comment: @fdermishin it is different language. We discuss C, you talk about C++. C++ and C are different languages!!

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't notice that